# How to move paging from data-table and make it works

Tags: devexpress, angular7, devextreme

here is my template: ( here i am trying to implement paging from outside of the data table,not works!!)

```
        <div id="outside">

            <dxo-pager
                [showInfo]="true"
                infoText="Page #{0}. Total: {1} ({2} items)"
                [showPageSizeSelector]="true"
                [allowedPageSizes]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"
                [showNavigationButtons]="true">
            </dxo-pager>

        </div>

        <dx-data-grid [dataSource]="courseList | async" #dataTable  id="gridContainer"
        [customizeColumns]="customizeColumns"
        (onRowPrepared)="onRowPrepared('cellInfo')"
        (onCellPrepared)="onCellPrepared($event)"
        (onEditingStart)="logEvent('EditingStart')"
        (onInitNewRow)="logEvent('InitNewRow')"
        (onRowInserting)="logEvent('RowInserting')"
        (onRowInserted)="logEvent('RowInserted')"
        (onRowUpdating)="logEvent('RowUpdating')"
        (onRowUpdated)="logEvent('RowUpdated')"
        (onRowRemoving)="logEvent('RowRemoving')"
        (onRowRemoved)="logEvent('RowRemoved')">
        <dx-data-grid>
```

my question is what is the right way to paging from outside for a data table?
simply: how to connect from outside with required data table?

Comment: `dxo-pager` must belong to a `dx-data-grid`. There is no direct way to implement it from my knowledge (you may open an issue on github for that). The best you can do is using `dataTable.instance` and manually change the `DataSource` page index manually: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Methods/#pageIndexnewIndex

Comment: @briosheje, your clue is Ok, but how to show the paging? [1,2,3,4] ( page numbers ), next, previous can be manged from methods.

Comment: I don't know, I think you can look at the DataSource documentation according to the DataSource type you're getting. Personally, I would avoid making a so deep change to a behavior written by the devexpress team: making your own paginator means taking care of a whole lot of things. I would suggest you to directly open a ticket on GitHub, since such request requires **a lot** of work, I've never seen anyone needing to replace an entire part of a widget and, particularly, the dx-data-grid is the one of their biggest widgets.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at this: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T505809/dxdatagrid-how-to-implement-a-custom-pager